# WPF ListView Grids equivalent of AutogeneratedColumns event?

Tags: wpf, listview

When using a standard (i.e not a DataGrid) ListView Grid control, is there an equivalent of the AutogeneratedColumns event? I want to allow the selection of which columns to be selected by a user at run time, and then saved between appliation runs?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answers is basically no.

I would probably have to use something like the solution in this [project](http://gridviewcolumncollec.codeplex.com/)